# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Entry' and 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to make a Pythagoras Theorem Calculator using Tkinter on Python 33, but I'm running into a slight problem.

Heres my code -

```
from tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()

L1 = Label(root, text="A = ")
L1.pack()

E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)
E1.pack()

L2 = Label(root, text="B = ")
L2.pack()

E2 = Entry(root, bd =5)
E2.pack()

asq = E1**2
bsq = E2**2

csq = asq + bsq
ans = math.sqrt(csq)

def showsum():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Answer =", ans)

B1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Click This To Calculate!", command = showsum())
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And here is my error message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dale/Desktop/programming/Python/tkinterpythagoras.py", line 18, in     <module>
    asq = E1**2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Entry' and 'int'
```

Please don't go rough on me. I'm a complete beginner with Tkinter!

Comment: What are you intending that to do?

Comment: It should give out the side of C on a triangle, using Pythagoras Theorem

Answer (score 3):

You have some problems in your program: First of all, `E1` and `E2` are Entry widgets, not numbers, so you have to retrieve the value first:

```
try:
    val = int(E1.get())
except ValueError:
    # The text of E1 is not a valid number
```

Secondly, in the command option of the Button you are calling the function `showsum()` instead of passing the reference:

```
B1 = Button(root, ..., command=showsum)  # Without ()
```

Besides, this function always shows the same result previously calculated, so you should retrieve the value of the widgets in this function and not before. Finally, with `from tkinter import *` Button is in the global namespace, so you should remove the reference to `tkinter` before it.

So in the end `showsum` could be something similar to this:

```
def showsum():
    try:
        v1, v2 = int(E1.get()), int(E2.get())
        asq = v1**2
        bsq = v2**2
        csq = asq + bsq
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Answer =", math.sqrt(csq))
    except ValueError:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("ValueError!")
```

Answer (score 2):

That error message is pretty clear. You are trying to raise an `Entry` object to some power, and you can't do that with `Entry` objects, because they are not numbers but user interface elements. Instead, you want what is *in* the `Entry` object, i.e. what the user has entered, and you probably want to convert it to an integer or float. So:

```
asq = float(E1.get()) ** 2
```